# How do I derive a particular form of the Langevin equation from Mori's generalized master equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equations-of-motion

**Preliminary:** I have a generalized Langevin equation for a set of relevant operators, written in Liouiville space as $\{|A_{v}\rangle \}$, and obtained via Mori's projection operator technique:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} |A_{v}(t)\rangle & = i e^{i\mathcal{L}t}\mathcal{P}\mathcal{L}|A_{v}(0)\rangle - \int^{t}_{0} e^{i\mathcal{L}(t - \tau)} \mathcal{P}\mathcal{L}e^{i\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}t}\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}|A_{v}(0)\rangle d\tau + i e^{i\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}\tau}\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}|A_{v}(0)\rangle, \tag{1}\label{eq: Mori langevin 1}
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the classical Liouvillian operator and $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ are standard projection operators defined by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P} & = \sum_{ww'} \frac{|A_{w}\rangle\langle A_{w'}|}{\langle A_{w}| A_{w'}\rangle} \tag{2} \\
\mathcal{Q} & = 1 - \mathcal{P}, \tag{3}
\end{align}
where $w$ runs over the space of relevant variables. Eq. \ref{eq: Mori langevin 1} requires the Liouville space to have a defined scalar product: $\langle F | G \rangle = c$, where $c$ is some complex number. I don't think it's necessary to specifically define this scalar product, but of course the usual choices apply.

If we further define several quantities:
\begin{align}
\text{the frequency matrix: } & \:\:\:  \Omega_{wv} = \sum_{w'} \frac{\langle A_{w'} | \mathcal{L} A_{v} \rangle}{\langle w|w' \rangle} \tag{4}\\
\text{the friction coefficient: } & \:\:\:  \gamma_{wv}(\tau) = \sum_{w'} \frac{\langle A_{w'} | \mathcal{L}e^{i\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}\tau}\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}A_{v}\rangle}{\langle w|w' \rangle} \tag{5}\\
\text{the residual force: } & \:\:\:  f_{v}(t) = i e^{i\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}t}\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{L}|A_{v}\rangle, \tag{6}
\end{align}
we get the very recognisable
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} A_{v}(t) & = i\sum_{w} \Omega_{wv}A_{w}(t) - \int^{t}_{0} \sum_{w} \gamma_{wv}(\tau)A_{w}(t - \tau) d\tau + f_{v}(t). \tag{7}
\end{align}

**Question:** I am interested in dynamics described by the position, $x$, and momentum (or velocity if mass is unity), $v = \dot{x}$. The Mori equations of motion are now
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) & = i \Omega_{xx}x(t) + i \Omega_{x\dot{x}}\dot{x}(t) - \int^{t}_{0} \left[\gamma_{xx}(\tau)x(t - \tau) + \gamma_{x\dot{x}}(\tau)\dot{x}(t - \tau)\right] d\tau + f_{x}(t) \label{eq: Mori langevin 2} \tag{8}\\
\ddot{x}(t) & = i \Omega_{\dot{x}x}x(t) + i \Omega_{\dot{x}\dot{x}}\dot{x}(t) - \int^{t}_{0} \left[\gamma_{\dot{x}x}(\tau)x(t - \tau) + \gamma_{\dot{x}\dot{x}}(\tau)\dot{x}(t - \tau)\right] d\tau + f_{\dot{x}}(t). \tag{9}\label{eq: Mori langevin 3}
\end{align}
The literature suggests that we can apply the constraint $v = \dot{x}(t)$ to get a form like
\begin{align}
\ddot{x}(t) & = F(x) - \int^{t}_{0} \gamma(\tau)\dot{x}(t - \tau) d\tau + f(t), \tag{10}\label{eq: what i want}
\end{align}
where we can interpret $F(x)$ as the force due to some potential. See for example Eqn 17a-17b of https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5021 or Chapter 8.5 of Zwanzig's 'Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics', (which is for a system interacting bilinearly with a harmonic oscillator heat bath). However, I can't see how to get from Eq. \ref{eq: Mori langevin 2} and Eq. \ref{eq: Mori langevin 3} to Eq.\ref{eq: what i want}. I have tried just directly rearranging Eq. \ref{eq: Mori langevin 2} and Eq. \ref{eq: Mori langevin 3}, or solving one and putting it in the other, but I'm always left with either a $\dot{x}$ outside the integral or an $x$ inside the integral. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Can I even do it generally or do I need a specific Hamiltonian and definition for the scalar product?